# Firebase Security Permissions telling that a string is not a string while using isString

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I'm sending my token to the server but something is wrong. I went to test out my permissions on Firebase simulator  and found out that the `.validate` line is telling me that it's wrong. Here's my security rules

```
{
    "rules":{
        "tokens":{
        "users":{
                "$uid":{
                  ".read":"auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
                  ".validate":"newData.isString()", // wrong here. idk why
                  ".write":"auth !== null && $uid === auth.uid && (!data.exists() || newData.val() !== data.val())"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data structure:

```
root
  |-  tokens
       |- users
           |- uid:token_value
```

My input are as follows:

**Simulation Type:** Write

**Location:** /tokens/users/hA4hZrBieISwMOZaMYe7m6K5tpI3

Data (JSON):

```
{
  "hA4hZrBieISwMOZaMYe7m6K5tpI3": "hi"
}
```

**Authenticated:** True

**Provider:** Google

**UID:** hA4hZrBieISwMOZaMYe7m6K5tpI3

Problem is the `"hi"` in the Data (JSON) is said to be a non-string value. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new data that you're writing to `/tokens/users/hA4hZrBieISwMOZaMYe7m6K5tpI3` is not a string, it's a JSON object:

```
{
  "hA4hZrBieISwMOZaMYe7m6K5tpI3": "hi"
}
```

To validate that `hA4hZrBieISwMOZaMYe7m6K5tpI3` is a string value:

```
{
    "rules":{
        "tokens":{
            "users":{
               "$uid":{
                  ".read":"auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
                  "$key": {
                     ".validate":"newData.isString()"
                  },
                  ".write":"auth !== null && $uid === auth.uid && (!data.exists() || newData.val() !== data.val())"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. It appears I'm a bit confused. Will the data structure follow the one I've provided in my question? or will it create another node under the first uid with the uid and token combined? Because I want it to look like `users/uid` and the `uid` will contain the token. What I'm thinking is revising the location that I'm setting it at to `tokens/users/` to achieve what I want but after that I'm lost

Comment: My guess is that you want to write a simple string (`"hi"`) to `/tokens/users/hA4hZrBieISwMOZaMYe7m6K5tpI3`. In that case your original rules are correct, but the problem is that you're trying to write a JSON object.